# Get offset in file read by BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io, filesize, bufferedreader

I'm reading a file line by line. The file is encoded by `CipherOutputStream` and then later compressed by `DeflaterOutputStream`. The file can consist of UTF-8 characters, like Russian letters, etc.

I want to obtain the offset in actually read file, or the number of bytes read by `br.ReadLine()` command. The problem is that the file is both encrypted, and deflated, so length of read String is larger than number of read bytes in file.

```
            InputStream fis=tempURL.openStream();                       //in tempURL I've got an URL to download
            CipherInputStream cis=new CipherInputStream(fis,pbeCipher); //CipherStream
            InflaterInputStream iis=new InflaterInputStream(cis);       //InflaterInputStream
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(iis, "UTF8"));                //BufferedReader
            br.readLine();

            int fSize=tempURL.openConnection().getContentLength();      //Catch FileSize
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) from the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) project:

```
InputStream fis=tempURL.openStream();
CountingInputStream countStream = new CountingInputStream(fis);
CipherInputStream cis=new CipherInputStream(countStream,pbeCipher);
...
```

Later you can obtain the file position with `countStream.getByteCount()`.

Comment: This will count the number of bytes read. The actual number of bytes used for the line read will be less than this (but this may be the best solution in any case)

Comment: nice idea, but I don't want to use external libraries, 'cause I use this code in Applet, so I want't to keep the smallest possible size of app. Acutally, I figure this out in another way - when I write to the file, at the beggining I'm counting number of lines to write in file, then I write this number to file, and while reading, I can know approx. progress of reading the file.
I will keep these topic for a few while, and then I'll close it. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For compressed files, you can find that a String doesn't use a whole number of bytes so the question cannot be answered. e.g. a byte can take less than a byte when compressed (otherwise there would be no point trying to compress it)

BTW: Is usually best to compress the data **before** encrypting it as it will usually be much more compact.  Compressing the data after it has been encrypted will only help if its output is base 64 or something similar.  Compression works best when you can the contents become predictable (e.g. repeating sequences, common characters) whereas the porpose of encryption is to make the data appear unpredictable.